# Make Detail View "Master" Button Title Always Be the Title of the Active Master View with Xcode 4.3.2 Storyboards

Tags: ios5, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

When in portrait layout my iPad app shows a button titled "Master", that when clicked will show the master detail controller. I want the title of this button to always be the title of the active master view. How do I make this happen?

https://github.com/kirkouimet/enzyme/blob/master/Enzyme/KODetailViewController.m#L86

And some pretty screens for fun:

[image]

And after you browse to the feed you want, the button title should change to "All" in this case:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your master view controller is a `UINavigationController`. If so, then you can do the following to grab the visible view controller's title from the navigation item:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)popoverController.contentViewController;
    barButtonItem.title = navigationController.visibleViewController.navigationItem.title;

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}
```